# Can I legally quit an Inc as a stakeholder

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, new-york-state

I am a co-founder of an Inc. I registered the corporation in New York a few years ago and now I want to quit it.

How do I do so ?
Do I also have to fill the DTF-17.1 form before I quit ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't *quit* from being a shareholder of a corporation. To cease having any relationship you must dispose of your shares by transferring them to someone else (with their agreement and either by sale or as a gift) or having the corporation buy them back (with the agreement of the corporation).